# Recursively go through all directories until you find a certain file in Python

Tags: python, file, recursion, directory

What's the best way in Python to recursively go through all directories until you find a certain file? 
I want to look through all the files in my directory and see if the file I'm looking for is in that directory.
If I cannot find it, I go to the parent directory and repeat the process. I also want to count 
how many directories and files I go through before I find the file. If there is no file at the 
end of the loop return that there is no file

startdir = "Users/..../file.txt"

findfile is name of file. This is my current loop but I want to make it work using recursion.

```
def walkfs(startdir, findfile):
    curdir = startdir
    dircnt = 0
    filecnt = 0
    for directory in startdir:
        for file in directory:
            curdir = file
            if os.path.join(file)==findfile:
                return (dircnt, filecnt, curdir)
            else:
                dircnt+=1
                filecnt+=1
```

Comment: Either the `glob` module or `os.listdir`, probably.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't re-invent the directory-recursion wheel. Just use the [`os.walk()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), which gives you a loop over a recursive traversal of directories:

```
def walkfs(startdir, findfile):
    dircount = 0
    filecount = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
        if findfile in files:
            return dircount, filecount + files.index(findfile), os.path.join(root, findfile)
        dircount += 1
        filecount += len(files)
    # nothing found, return None instead of a full path for the file
    return dircount, filecount, None
```

Comment: i think he said he just wants to return the first path he finds

Comment: @JoranBeasley: and what makes you think this doesn't do that?

Comment: derr... sorry ... i just saw the count stuff like an idiot thought you were counting matches :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: *I also want to count how many directories and files I go through before I find the file*

Answer (score 0):

```
def findPath(startDir,targetFile):
    file_count = 0
    for i,(current_dir,dirs,files) in enumerate(os.walk(startDir)):
        file_count += len(files)
        if targetFile in files:
           return (i,file_count,os.path.join(current_dir,targetFile))
    return (i,file_count,None)

print findPath("C:\\Users\\UserName","some.txt")
```