# Using BeautifulSoup 4 and recursion to capture the structure of HTML nested tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to capture the layout of an HTML page using BeautifulSoup4 and recursion. The idea is to have linked data structures of parents to children, for example, a layout like this:

```
<html>
 <h1>
  <!--Contents-->
 </h1>
 <div> 
  <div> 
   <!--Contents-->
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Would be stored in a list like so:

```
html = [ h1 , div ] # Where h1 and div are also lists also containing lists
```

I've had a hard time finding Q&A on this specific problem, so instead I've tried modeling a function off of using recursion to traverse [directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879638/recursively-go-through-all-directories-until-you-find-a-certain-file-in-python) as they're pretty similar.

This is my current function in Python 3 that's supposed to nest tags into lists:

```
def listGen(l , hObj):
    # Where hObj is a BS4 object and l is a sorted lists containing direct children to the html tag
    z = []
    for x in l:
        z.append(hObj.find(x).children)

    def expand(xlist1):
        # Where xlist1 is a list generator 
        for n in xlist1:
            if n.name is not None:
                print(n.name)
                for n2 in hObj.find(n.name).children:
                    if n2.name is not None:
                        print(n2.name , "--") #Debugging print              
        return z #Temporary
    for x in z:
        print("------")
        expand(x , 0)
    return z
```

Parsing the [Wikipedia Home Page](https://www.wikipedia.org/) gives me an output of:

```
------
h1
img --
div --
div
div --
strong --
div
div --
strong --
div
div --
strong --
div
div --
strong --
div
div --
strong --
hr
div
div --
strong --
p
small --
small --
small --
script
script
script
style
------
meta
title
meta
script
meta
link
link
link
style
style
link
link
```

Which is exactly what I need, ***however*** it takes two for loops and will take many more to get all the children of children. Furthermore I wouldn't know how much tags nest from future websites. So I changed the `expand` function to:

```
def expand(xlist1 , depth): 
    l1 = list(xlist1)
    if depth < len(l1):
        for n in l1[depth]:
            if n is not None:
                if hObj.find(l1[depth].name).children:
                    return expand(hObj.find(l1[depth].name).children , 0)
            if n is None:
                print(2) # Debugging print
                return expand(xlist1 , depth + 1)
    if depth >= len(l1):
        return 0 # Temporary
    return 0 # Temporary
```

Only to give me maximum recursion errors, I've tried many other variations of it all to no avail.

I've scoured through the [BS4 Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) multiple times and there seems to be no built in function for this. Any suggestions or is this not a viable way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that nested lists are exactly what you're looking for here. If all you're trying to do is build a tree of tags, I would use nested dictionaries. I would still use them if you're trying to extract any other information.

**This recursive function will build a nested-dictionary "tree"**

```
def traverse(soup):
    if soup.name is not None:
        dom_dictionary = {}
        dom_dictionary['name'] = soup.name
        dom_dictionary['children'] = [ traverse(child) for child in soup.children if child.name is not None]
        return dom_dictionary
```

**We can use it like so:**

```
page = requests.get("http://example.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html5lib")
traverse(soup)
```

This gives us:

```
{'name': '[document]',
 'children': [{'name': 'html',
   'children': [{'name': 'head',
     'children': [{'name': 'title', 'children': []},
      {'name': 'meta', 'children': []},
      {'name': 'meta', 'children': []},
      {'name': 'meta', 'children': []},
      {'name': 'style', 'children': []}]},
    {'name': 'body',
     'children': [{'name': 'div',
       'children': [{'name': 'h1', 'children': []},
        {'name': 'p', 'children': []},
        {'name': 'p', 'children': [{'name': 'a', 'children': []}]}]}]}]}]}
```